# Override theme metadata in header

Tags: headers, facebook

I've recently purchased and heavily customized a new WP theme, but am having problems with metadata. When posting a link to the in Facebook, the meta data pulls in the theme author name ... [image: facebook screenshot]

As we've paid for this theme and heavily adapted it to our needs, I don't feel that the theme author should appear here. The Style sheet obviously should credit them, but not metadata (please tell me if you think I'm wrong here).

I've tried removing the  from the header.php and I use the Yoast SEO plugin, but I can't remove this one thing that Facebook pulls in.

Would greatly appreciate any help on this.

Thanks.

Comment: Very strange, I don't see any mention of that in your source code. I would recommend searching your the entire theme + any plugins that came with it for the phrase 'By DEVN CO'

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I can't find a search tool that indexes all css sheets throughout the entire theme. I don't think Firebug has that facility. Any suggestions without going through manually?

Comment: Yes :) Download Sublime Text (free) and use their find in all files function to search through a local version of your theme.

Comment: You could probably just use your computers built in search function to search within the theme folder too. But Sublime Text is a good one to have anyways.